# How does PostgreSQL implement the REPEATABLE_READ isolation level?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transaction-isolation

The REPEATABLE_READ transaction isolation level of PostgreSQL 12 prevents dirty reads, non-repeatable reads, and phantom reads. In contrast to the READ_COMMITTED isolation level, the REPEATABLE_READ isolation level prevents non-repatable reads and phantom reads.

I guess that this comes with a cost, otherwise one would just make both equal. How does postgres guarantee that those 3 read phenomena don't occur?

Comment: You probably already found [Concurrency Control](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql05.html), which seems to talk about this from chapter 5.4

Comment: @Luuk This link is AWESOME! If you post this (+ maybe add a few words), I would accept it. Otherwise I'll summarize it in a few days :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`READ COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE READ` are using the same technology: a *snapshot* that determines which of the versions of a row in the table a transaction can see. The difference is that with `READ COMMITTED`, the snapshot is taken at the start of each statement, so that each new statement can see everything that has been committed before, while a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction uses the same snapshot for all statements.

There are two consequences:

- if anything, `REPEATABLE READ` is cheaper than `READ COMMITTED`, because it takes fewer snapshots
- `REPEATABLE READ` provides even higher isolation than required by the SQL standard – the database does not seem to change at all

The price you are paying for `REPEATABLE READ` is different:

- you risk serialization errors, which force you to repeat the transaction
- `VACUUM` cannot clean up rows marked dead after the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction started

Comment: Since in SQL Server you can control that behaviour: Do you know of situations in PgSQL, where the snapshot space exhausted or did other strange things?

Comment: No, that can never happen. Perhaps a snapshot in SQL Server is something different. A query snapshot in PostgreSQL is local to the connection that runs the query. It describes the transaction numbers whose data modifications the query can see.

Comment: But PgSQL needs to store it somewhere? My understanding: REPEATABLE READ in the past caused a Shared-Lock in SQL Server - so no update was possible. So the introduced Snapshots: https://youtu.be/NObahFaNmz4?t=79 - looks exactly the same beahviour as in PgSQL. But in SQL Server it needs planing since its consumes ressources.

Comment: Yes, the idea is the same (SQL Server figured out at some point that its default read locks were not such a great thing), but the implementation may be quite different.